# How to convert a selection to shape in a single step?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I wanted to know if there is a way using Photoshop (2015).

What I want to do is to convert a selection to shape, actually I use the Polygonal Lasso tool to draw my shape, convert the selection to path and define the path to shape.

However this way I'll need to pick the shape from the mene and enter it again in the same position, I'd like to avoid this and have my shape already placed / sized when defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Photoshop use the Pen Tool to make a shape. Make sure you set the Pen Tool to "Shape" in the tool options along the top.

Example

[image]

Note: in Illustrator, you would also use the Pen Tool for this. In Illustrator all vector objects are shapes (closed paths), or open paths. There's no specific "shape" setting.

Comment: omg, I'm a total noob, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a button in the middle at the bottom of the Paths palette that will convert your selection into a shape, if you are starting with a selection.